# CXF dynamic client API - getUnwrapperOperation, getWrappedOperation

Tags: web-services, api, cxf

```
QName opName = new QName("http://mycompany.com/soap/service", "Login");
BindingOperationInfo boi = binding.getOperation(lastOperation);
boi = boi.getUnwrappedOperation();
boi = boi.getWrappedOperation();
```

Can anyone explain to me the difference between getUnwrappedOperation() vs. getWrappedOperation()? What is being wrapped?

Answer (score 1):

The difference depends on how you would "like" to use the operation.   With Doc/Literal endpoints, most use a "wrapped" form where you end up with a schema like:

with an operation named "doStuff" that points to the above as the single element part in the input message.

When you call the client with the "unwrapped" operation, the runtime will expect you to send in the 3 parameters, a String, and int, and a String.    With the wrapped operation, the runtime will expect you to send in a single "DoStuffRequest" object with the data held in it.

Basically, it just depends on how you plan to work with the operation and how it matches your dataset.